# Is there provision to create a multiplexed connection to the Nest API?

Tags: nest-api

I would like to be able to receive updates from Nest for multiple users over a single connection?  Is this possible using any of the existing mechanics? If not, does anyone know if nest will be likely to support this type of connection in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplexing is not available right now, but will be in the coming months.

Comment: Do you know where exactly to look to be up to date on this?

Comment: Sign up as a developer. Emails go out to all registered developers on larger updates.